# Como definir o generator (do firebird) para um campo do modelo do Entity framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird

Por exemplo:

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
TABLE_EXAMPLO 
-----------
ID         
NAME
```

E o seguinte Generator:

```
TABLE_EXAMPLO_GEN
```

Como eu mapearia a entidade para que o Entity Framework possa chamar o generator para novo registros?

Em NHibernate era necessário algo como isso, em `ClassMap<T>`:

```
Id(t => t.Id).GeneratedBy.Native("TABLE_EXAMPLO_GEN").Column("ID");
// ou
Id(t => t.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("TABLE_EXAMPLO_GEN").Column("ID");
```

E em EntityFramwork isso é possível?

> Obs: Eu já tenho (no sistema legado) uma base de dados em Firebird nesse formato, com generator para as chaves primarias (sem triggers).

Comment: você já tentou colocar `Identity`: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`?

Comment: E como ele vai saber que o generator desse campo é o `TABLE_EXAMPLO_GEN`? @VirgilioNovic.

Comment: Então, você fez o teste ou não, eu te fiz uma pergunta?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, não, por que isso não faz nenhum sentido de funcionar como esperado!

Comment: Então, sem testar fica dificil saber se o provider que você utiliza preve tal operação. Um exemplo claro é Oracle, hoje ele funciona corretamente, mas, no inicio não funcionava. Qual o provider ou package que está utilizando? Não pode afirmar sem testar @Fernando.

Answer (score 1):

Com uma base de dados Firebird, foi criado um tabela com os seguintes campos:

```
/* Table: CLIENTE, Owner: SYSDBA */

CREATE TABLE "CLIENTE" 
(
  "ID"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "NOME"     VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET WIN1251 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_CLIENTE" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

e para o auto-incremento do campo `ID` um `Generator`:

```
/* Triggers only will work for SQL triggers */
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER "SET_CUST_NO" FOR "CLIENTE" 
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
    if (new.ID is null) then
    new.ID = gen_id(cust_no_gen, 1);
END
 ^    
COMMIT WORK ^
SET TERM ;^
```

sendo assim, todo cadastro o `ID` vai ser incrementado.

---

***Como configurar o EntityFramework para funcionar o mapeamento:***

**Baixe os pacotes:**

- [EntityFramework 6.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/)
- [Firebird Entity Framework Provider 5.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Firebird/)
- [Firebird ADO.NET Data provider 5.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/)

**Classes:**

*1) Modelo:*

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

*2) Mapeamento:*

```
public sealed class ClienteConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("CLIENTE");

        HasKey(c => c.Id)
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(c => c.Nome)
            .HasColumnName("NOME")
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

*3) Context*

```
public sealed class Database: DbContext
{
    public Database()
        :base("FireBirdConnectionString")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClienteConfiguration());            
    }
}
```

*4) Configuração de conexão:*

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FireBirdConnectionString"
    connectionString="DataSource=localhost; User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey; Database=C:\Temp\TUTORIAL.FDB;" 
    providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

---

**Seu questionamento:**

*Como eu mapearia a entidade para que o Entity Framework possa chamar o generator para novo registros?*

Foi colocado `.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`, e funcionou, foi removido essa configuração, também funcionou, **ou seja**, o provider se encarrega de executar o insert com `Generator`, sem configuração.

Logo, se sua tabela estiver configurada com `Generator` o `provider`: `Firebird Entity Framework Provider` faz a ação e te retorna na `classe` o `ID` gerado.

Comment: Entendi o que você propôs, até já tinha pensando em algo como isso, só que era exatamente isso que eu não queria pois estou trabalhando em uma base de dados legado que já trabalha em Delphi e em .net com NHibernate, e não seria a primeira opção criar TRIGGERs para todas as chaves das tabelas =\. Mas mesmo assim obrigado pela sugestão +1 =D. Vou aguardar para ver se não há uma solução como a do NHibernate.

Comment: Só uma duvida, existe outra forma? de gerar os números? é que fiz pesquisas e pesquisas e foi a unica maneira que achei ...? Não é com TRIGGERS?

Comment: Não sei! Essa é exatamente a minha questão e duvida com essa pergunta! Também fiz uma longa pesquisa antes de postar aqui e não obtive sucesso, então resolvi tentar aqui no SOpt e no [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39456583/2290538) para ter melhor ideia do problema e das possíveis soluções (como a que você sugeriu!).